# How to simulate killing of application by Android GC

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I need to test serialization\deserialization of application in next cases:

- app was in background a lot of time (idle mode) and was killed by GC;
- app was in background and was killed by GC by reason of resources (memory\cp) lack;

On some devices it can be simulated by launching 1-2 games.
But on quad-core devices with 1gb memory it's very-very hard with 4-10 heavy games and takes a lot of time.

I try to implement some demo where emulating loading on resources:

- create bitmaps arrays
- create objects arrays
- launch a lot of services
- launch a lot of activities

But no result, application still works (even on old devices) and my demo is crashed with OutOfMemoryException.

How can i simulate high load in demo application?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a developer option under setting 'Don't keep activities' which is meant to destray the activity as soon as the user leaves it.

Comment: I got that option @Ifor mentioned on my 4.0 android but on 2.3 I think hadn't (I upgraded it)

Comment: @Ifor, thanks, but it's absolutely different. In case with 'Don't keep activities' will be called onDestroy and application will be closed normally (like common exit from app).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the "GC" is actually abused "Out Of Memory Killer" and that kills the applications as if by signal 9. In rooted device you should be able to invoke [kill(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) command from shell or [kill(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) function from native library (I am not sure whether it's bound to Java) and kill your application whenever you want.

The system normally calls `onStop` in the `Activity` when it's going to background and than kills the application without further warning and without chance to react. So if you leave the application and kill it, it's appropriate simulation of it being OOM-killed.

Comment: It's looks like a truth and i thought the same. But if you check activity callbacks and logs you will see absolutely different behavior. When you kill app from Task Manager, it looks like normal exit from app(with onDestroy and correct finishing).

Comment: @nister: When you kill it from Task Manager it might be so. But the question is what happens when the application is killed because of memory shortage.

Comment: When Android kills the app because of memory constraint and then the app is opened by the user, the last activity is opened. When manually killing the app, only the main activity is restored.

Answer (score 0):

Install any memory cleaner on play store. I install this : [easymemorycleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kosajun.easymemorycleaner)

once u cleaned your memory. Your stored variable inside memory will be gone. Unless you stored data in Parcelable. It will be persistent.